# Dart pub install x86_64 SocketIOException

Tags: linux, dart, dart-pub

Trying to run "pub install" for a project, following the instructions here:
http://news.dartlang.org/2013/01/big-breaking-change-dartjs-bootstrap-file-moving-to-pub.html

and here:

http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/browser

I'm getting an exception with the full verbose output below when trying to call pub install.

I'm using dart SDK version 0.2.9.9_r16323 on x86_64 Ubuntu linux.

What should I do differently to get the browser package to install?

Trace:

```
joe@joe-desktop-2:~/shared/programming/appengine/joesarre/tstormdart$ pub -v install
IO  : Seeing if file /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/pubspec.yaml exists.
IO  : File /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/pubspec.yaml exists.
IO  : Reading text file /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/pubspec.yaml.
IO  : Read /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/pubspec.yaml. Contents:
    | name:  tstormdart
    | description:  A sample application
    | 
    | dependencies:
    | #  js: any
    | #  unittest: { sdk: unittest }
    |    browser: any
    | 
    | 
FINE: Loading lockfile.
IO  : Seeing if file /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/pubspec.lock exists.
IO  : File /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/pubspec.lock exists.
IO  : Reading text file /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/pubspec.lock.
IO  : Read /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/pubspec.lock. Contents:
    | {"packages":{}}
MSG : Resolving dependencies...
FINE: Adding (entrypoint)'s constraint tstormdart 0.0.0 from root (tstormdart).
FINE: Changing tstormdart to version 0.0.0.
FINE: Adding tstormdart's constraint browser any from hosted (browser).
IO  : Sending HTTP request GET http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/browser.json.
FINE: Got response 200 OK.
FINE: Changing browser to version 0.9.0.
IO  : Sending HTTP request GET http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/browser/versions/0.9.0.yaml.
FINE: Got response 200 OK.
IO  : Seeing if directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages exists.
IO  : Directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages exists.
IO  : Begin delete directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages.
IO  : End delete directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages.
IO  : Begin create directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages.
IO  : End create directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages.
FINE: Ensuring directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages exists.
IO  : Seeing if directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages exists.
IO  : Directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages exists.
FINE: Directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages already exists.
IO  : Seeing if file /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages/browser exists.
IO  : Seeing if directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages/browser exists.
IO  : File /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages/browser does not exist.
IO  : Directory /media/mass/home/joe/programming/tstormdart/packages/browser does not exist.
IO  : Seeing if file /home/joe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.9.0 exists.
IO  : Seeing if directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.9.0 exists.
IO  : File /home/joe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.9.0 does not exist.
IO  : Directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org/browser-0.9.0 does not exist.
FINE: Ensuring directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org exists.
IO  : Seeing if directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org exists.
IO  : Directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org exists.
FINE: Directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dartlang.org already exists.
MSG : Downloading browser 0.9.0...
IO  : Sending HTTP request GET http://pub.dartlang.org/packages/browser/versions/0.9.0.tar.gz.
FINE: Ensuring directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/_temp exists.
IO  : Seeing if directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/_temp exists.
IO  : Directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/_temp does not exist.
FINE: Ensuring directory /home/joe/.pub-cache exists.
IO  : Seeing if directory /home/joe/.pub-cache exists.
IO  : Directory /home/joe/.pub-cache exists.
FINE: Directory /home/joe/.pub-cache already exists.
IO  : Begin create directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/_temp.
IO  : End create directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/_temp.
IO  : Begin create temp directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/_temp/dir.
IO  : End create temp directory /home/joe/.pub-cache/_temp/dir.
Unhandled exception:
SocketIOException: Unexpected handshake error in client (OS Error: errno = -12268)
#0      _SecureFilterImpl.handshake (dart:io-patch:870:8)
#1      _SecureSocket._secureHandshake (dart:io:7393:27)
#2      _SecureSocket._secureConnectHandler._secureConnectHandler (dart:io:7305:21)
#3      _Socket._updateOutHandler.firstWriteHandler (dart:io-patch:773:64)
#4      _SocketBase._multiplex (dart:io-patch:408:26)
#5      _SocketBase._sendToEventHandler.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch:509:20)
#6      _ReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch:37:92)
```

Comment: What's the point of using such an outdated Dart version?
Dart 1.0 is out for a while now (build 30798 instead of 16323).

Comment: I just downloaded the one from the home page at https://www.dartlang.org/ and assumed it would be the latest stable version.  Do you know where to find an updated version?

Comment: found it was possible to update from editor -> Help -> About. Going to give it another try now

Comment: There must something gone very wrong. Can you try to download from https://www.dartlang.org/tools/editor/ (using the links in the paragraph below the big download buttons mentioning "dev channel")?

Comment: Updating from within the editor got me to Dart SDK version 1.1.0-dev.4.0 which I can see is the same as the version from the links you describe.  Using the updated version I no longer have any issues.  Thanks for helping me get there - if you put that as the answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to download the Linux x64 version and I got the current version.

Glad to see that updating from your outdated version worked (Help > About > Check for Update).